# VB script within HTA Getting script to check service and loop until its started

Tags: loops, vbscript, hta

This is going in an HTA and have checked the VB Script for HTA compatibility. While its clear I don't have a scooby about most of the VB Scripting language I try my best.

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\Cimv2") 

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "Select * From Win32_Service where Name= 'spooler'")

For Each objItem In colItems 
    If objItem.State = "Running" Then
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        objShell.ShellExecute """C:\Program Files\Program\program.exe""" 
    ElseIf objItem.State = "Stopped" Then

        Empty code area

    End If
Next
```

In the empty code area , I am struggling to get something working.  I tried:

```
Do

Loop Until objItem.State = "Running"
```

This caused the HTA to hang as a "warning Script is not responding error".

Currently trying to find something along those lines but just wondered if anybody had any better suggestions.

Cheers

D

Comment: In the title you say VB, the tags says VBA. These are two different languages. VB stands for VB.NET, VBA for Visual Basic for Applications used in Word, Excel, Access etc. There is also VB Script, yet another language. You don't explain what you are looking for. A good question could be phrased as: "How can I test whether the spooler is running?". And add the appropriate tags like `vb` or `vba` and `windows`. It is also a good idea to mention the technology used like `winforms`, `asp.net`, `asp mvc` or `wpf` etc. What is HTA?

Comment: VBA was a typo :) not putting VB script is just my poor understanding of programming language's and HTA is an HTML application that can be used with VB script or java plus others. You are right the question could have been phrased better.

Comment: Changed title to be more explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

I have done some investigations. `colItems` seems to be of type `SWbemObjectSet`. This is a COM object which does not behave like most VB, VBA, VBScript collections. This should work:

```vb
Dim i

For i = 0 To colItems.Count - 1
    If colItems.ItemIndex(i).State = "Running" Then
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        objShell.ShellExecute """C:\Program Files\Program\program.exe""" 
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

I also added an `Exit For` because you want to start program.exe only once.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, Need to test this a bit further as it errors out with Expected '=' in the "for I = 0" line. will test further and see how it goes. Probably just my implentation of the code you have given to the script.

Comment: Sorry this does look like it is not working for me any ideas. After replacing the 'for' statement in my script for yours still doesn't work.